# Angular - Nested API Calls

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I'm getting data from APIs like this:

```js
this.myService.getFirstData(slug).pipe(takeUntil(this.unsubscribe))
      .subscribe(firstData => {
        this.data = firstData;
        for (const column of this.data.columns) {
          if(column.Type == 'List'){
            // Another API call here for this type of data. Note: I need to link them for populating a form (like => firstData[0] : dataFromSecondApiCall)
           }else if(column.Type == 'Enum')
            {
             // Another API call here for this type of data
            }
            And so on...
         }
       });
```

I already performed these API calls and get my data, but I wanted a more efficient way(maybe with forkJoin ?) to do this since I need all the two API data for populating a form.

Comment: If data is not paginated better to make it a single api. The if condition that you wrote if checked in backend it will make things more easier. Single form single api call.

Comment: @KrishnadasPC They are

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the problem right, this is the way I would implement this requirement. The comments try to explain the code.

```
this.myService.getFirstData(slug).pipe(
  // after getFirstData returns you can concatenate another series of http 
  // calls using the concatMap operator
  concatMap(firstData => {
     this.data = firstData;
     // we create an array to store the Observables that represent the
     // next calls we want to make
     let nextCalls Observable<any> = []
     for (const column of this.data.columns) {
       if(column.Type == 'List'){
         // depending on the type of column we push into the array a different
         // type of http request in the form of an Observable
         nextCalls.push(buildNextCallForList())
       } else if (column.Type == 'Enum') {
         nextCalls.push(buildNextCallForEnum())
       }
     }
     // eventually we exit concatMap returning the Observable returned by forkJoin
     // forkJoin will execute all the next http calls concurrently
     // and return an array with all the responses received
     return forkJoin(nextCalls)
  }),
  tap(dataFromSecondCalls => {
    // here you need to find if there is a way to link the results obtained
    // by the next calls with the data retrieved with the first call
    // and with what you want to achieve as final result
  })
)
// you can now subscribe
subscribe()
```

I have not tried this code myself, so there may be syntactical errors, but I hope the spirit of the code is clear.

Consider that you probably do not need the `takeUntil` operator since this seems to be an http call and http calls produce a stream that notifies only 1 value (or errors) and complete immediately afterwords. So there is no need to unsubscribe it with `takeUntil`.

You may find some inspiration about how to use Observables in http scenarios [looking at this article](https://betterprogramming.pub/rxjs-patterns-emerging-from-stackoverflow-asynchronous-api-calls-as-streams-in-the-real-world-ef636c9af19a).

Comment: @Drenai `concatMap` is an operator that can be piped in any stream transformation. It is often used to concatenate http calls. Can you explain in more details your comment?

Comment: @Drenai there is no difference between "multiple sequential emits" and "just one emit". You may have to concat that one emit with a following Observable. This is the standard practice when you have to call an http service and, based on the results returned, call a subsequent http service. In order to be able to do this sequential series of calls you either use `concatMap` or `swichMap`. The first is the default choice, the second is the choice when you want to kill in-fly requests when upstream notifies a new value. You may find the article I have linked in the response interesting.

Comment: @Drenai let me ask you something. How would you implement the following scenario. You have to call `httpServiceOne`, receive the answer and then call `httpServiceTwo` with data received from the first call as parameters of the second call?